# Closed Intervals help in Swift

Tags: swift, contains, intervals

I want to compare 2 different closed intervals to check if they have any overlap

```
var a = 1.0 ... 5.0

var x = 2.5 ... 6.5
var y = 0.5 ... 7.0
var z = 5.5 ... 8.0

compare(a,x) //should return true
compare(a,y) //should return true
compare(a,z) //should return false
```

does swift have any function like this built in? All I could find that was close was a contains method for intervals but I get an [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r578v.png) when I do that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `overlaps` method

```
a.overlaps(x) // return true
a.overlaps(y) // return true
a.overlaps(z) // return false
```